# highlighting cell with value closest to zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, highlighting

For example, I have this data 1.5, 1.2, -0.98, 1.01, and I want the cell with the value closest to zero to be highlighted. I tried to create the corresponding rule (see picture) but EXCEL does not color any cell. In my example, the cell with -0.98, since this is the value closest to zero, should be colored.

My first attempt

[image: My first attempt]

Comment: What about formula like as `=ABS(P74)=1/MAX(ABS(IFERROR(1/$P$74:$P$79;0)))`?

Comment: No, this does not work either.

Comment: Once more - not "cell value" but "formula" (last position in list of options)

Comment: Sorry I retried it and it worked! Maybe write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: I don't have Excel with an English interface right now, so I won't be able to take the necessary screenshots. Feel free to post your answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is another formula, it's easier to read, also it'll highlight also 0 (which won't be highlighted by currently posted answer).

`=ABS(C2)=MIN(ABS($C$2:$C$11))`

[image]

Comment: ,, nice one +10 ☺

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution created by @JohnSUN, who asked me to provide screenshots of an English EXCEL version. The trick is to use his formula and 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' as rule type, see screenshot.

[image: JohnSUN's solution.]

Comment: ,, nice one +10 ☺

Answer (score -1):

This also fixes the issue:

[image]

**N.B.**

- *I've given little twist & used cell references in the formula for
  Conditional Formatting, which makes it dynamic.*
- Formula in use: `=ABS(D31-$E$31)=MIN(ABS($D$31:$D$37-$E$31))`
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed, as well the Criteria
  in cell `E31`.